# Opening apps like photoshop using Java

Tags: java, macos

I am having some difficulty opening apps via MacOSX using Java.
I used to use sth like this

```
public class HelloWorldApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/open -a Terminal.app");
    }
}
```

but some of these apps like google chrome, photo booth and photoshop (or any app with space i.e two words) wont work

`/usr/bin/open -a Google\ Chrome.app` this is the exact code that opens google chrome via Terminal and I modified this code to make it fit for my project like this

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String s=("/usr/bin/open -a Google\\ Chrome.app");
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(s);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

But It won't work. Same thing with photoshop `("/usr/bin/open -a Adobe Photoshop SC6.app")`
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What about adding quotes around the app name?  If that doesn't work, use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).  I've seen lots of instances where Runtime failed in interpreting multiple arguments, but all worked using ProcessBuilder.

Comment: Thank you for the response
That might actually work but the only problem is I have no idea on how to use process builder...


`Process p = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg").start();`

Does this mean sth like this?

`Process p = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/", "open -a Google\\ Chrome.app").start();`

If thats the case it provided me with permission denied error 
`java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/": error=13, Permission denied`
:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/open", "-a", "Google Chrome.app").start();
```